# What happens on AzureDevOps when Visual Studio subscription is removed or expires?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

A person of the team just left.
Her/his Visual Studio subscripion will be removed or will expire.

What will happen to her/his files and entries on Azure DevOps?
Are we going to lose some data?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question after some test:

- No data is lost
- Only access rights are updated